# Mockito with JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

My test fails, this is my testing class.

```
public class EmailGeneratorServiceTests {

    @Mock
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    EmailGeneratorService emailGeneratorService;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        emailGeneratorService = new EmailGeneratorService(javaMailSender);
    }


    @Test
    public void generateAndSendMessageSuccess() throws MessagingException, IOException {
        String email = "test@test.com";
        String body = "Some contents.";
        String subject = "Some subject";
        emailGeneratorService.generateAndSendMessage(email, body, subject);
        List<Message> inbox = Mailbox.get(email);
        //inbox.size === 0
        assertTrue(inbox.size() == 1);
        assertEquals(subject, inbox.get(0).getSubject());
        assertEquals(body, inbox.get(0).getContent());
    }
}
```

When I call inbox.size() I get 0, but expected 1. The server is smtp.

This is EmailGeneratorService.

```
@Service
public class EmailGeneratorService {
    SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage;
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    public EmailGeneratorService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
        this.simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
    }

    public void generateAndSendMessage (String email, String messageBody, String subject) {
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(email);
        simpleMailMessage.setText(messageBody);
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
    }
}
```

Please write what's wrong and explain what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capture `JavaMailSender` to get the argument and assert it.

```
ArgumentCaptor<SimpleMailMessage> emailCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SimpleMailMessage .class);
verify(javaMailSender, times(1)).send(emailCaptor.capture());

List<SimpleMailMessage> actualList = emailCaptor.getAllValues();
assertTrue(actualList.size() == 1);
assertEquals(subject, actualList.get(0).getSubject());
assertEquals(body, actualList.get(0).getContent());
```

and User `ErrorCollector` to assert multiple values, define it before `@Before` method like this:

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();
```

, And in assertion use it like this:

```
collector.checkThat(getResult(), equalTo("ERROR!"));
```

You test should be like this:

```
public class EmailGeneratorServiceTests {

    private static final String EMAIL = "test@test.com";
    private static final String BODY = "Some contents.";
    private static final String SUBJECT = "Some subject";

    @Mock
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    private EmailGeneratorService emailGeneratorService;

    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollecto();  

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        emailGeneratorService = new EmailGeneratorService(javaMailSender);
    }


    @Test
    public void generateAndSendMessageSuccess() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        emailGeneratorService.generateAndSendMessage(email, body, subject);

        // Act
        Mailbox.get(email);

        // Assert
        ArgumentCaptor<SimpleMailMessage> emailCaptor = 
        ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SimpleMailMessage .class);
        verify(javaMailSender, times(1)).send(emailCaptor.capture());

        List<SimpleMailMessage> actualList = emailCaptor.getAllValues();
        collector.checkThat(actualList.size(), equalTo(1));
        collector.checkThat(actualList.get(0).getSubject(), equalTo(SUBJECT));
        collector.checkThat(actualList.get(0).getContent(), equalTo(CONTENT));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you approve the answer :D

Comment: Would doing the generateAndSendMessage method from emailGeneratorService, in your @Test, actually send the email again, so like duplicate sending?